# Download specific bits of a file

Tags: networking, browser, download, protocols

Is there any networking protocol that helps in downloading specific bits of a file? Moreover is there any relation to this question and pause download that is available in browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To download a single piece of a file, you need a utility such as `curl` (curl.haxx.se)

```sh
curl -r 0-10000000 -o Output.bin http://adddress-to-the.file
```

this will download the first ten megabytes into `Output.bin`.

Comment: It seems server must also support range header!  Many servers arent allowing range specification.